# Bypassing geocodes query limit with settimeout

Tags: javascript, arrays, settimeout, geocoding

So, I am testing a script what would take cities from an array then find their coordinates with geocode and after that gets the zip of a city. Well, this works ok with one city, but with an array, geoCode has a query limit, so I am trying to bypass it with setTimeout, but since I am not yet amazing at js, it's not working out.

```
<head>
    <div id= "test"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

    function getLoc(){  
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = ["Helsinki", "Paris", "London"];
        for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++)    {
            setTimeout(function(i){ 
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address[i]}, function (results, status) {    
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                alert(long);
                getZip(lat, long);

                }
            });
            }, i* 1000);
        }
        }
        getLoc();
    function getZip(lat, long){
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': latlng
        }, function(results, status) {
            address = results[0].address_components;
            zipcode = address[address.length - 1].long_name;
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = zipcode;
        }); 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: I believe you are seeing lat and long for the last city "London"?

Comment: timeout works, but it doesn't go through first geocode request

Comment: I don't know your use case or the size of your data set but you might want to consider writing a server-side cron job that fetches data in background (with an appropriate throttle) and stores it in a database. The API limits are too low for real-time batch processing and adding intentional delay on the client can make visitor frustrated.

Comment: @Álvaro González Yea, I did read about it, but I am not going to use this anywhere public, I am only doing it to make things easier for myself. I might still try crone with it just for fun tho. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) { 
 (function(i){
  setTimeout(function(i){ 
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address[i]}, function (results, status) { if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(); var long = results[0].geometry.location.lng(); alert(long); getZip(lat, long); } });
   }, i* 1000);
   })(i);
}
```

The for loop will finish before the timeouts fire. So i will always be adress.length-1 in all Timeouts. You need to store i in every timeouts scope using an IIFE (may have a look at 'timeouts in a for loop' on SO)

As @iwrestledabearonce pointed out, using a timeout is not a elegant way. You could either use multiple open requests at a time, or one after another. For the first one you dont need a timeout, and for the second one, a recursive function is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrapp your `setTimeout` in closure function, for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
        setTimeout(function(i){ 
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address[i]}, function (results, status) {    
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    alert(long);
                    getZip(lat, long);

                }
            });
        }, i* 1000);
    })(i);
}
```

without closure your `i` in `setTimeout` will has always value from last `for` iterate

Comment: why someone minus this answer...?

Comment: i explained why this answer and the one above it are wrong in my own answer. question is, why did someone upvote an incorrect answer?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. so can you explain why this is wrong? it is another to implement what you wrote, it works the same way, but you're using the callback function.

Comment: no i can't, because it's not wrong. i just wasn't paying attention.  I didn't notice the `i* 1000`. my mistake. i removed the vote.

Comment: @I wrestled a bear once I like your name, also can I see your example somehow again?